# Adding Comma JavaScript Counter

Tags: javascript

I've looked at tolocalestring() and it doesn't work.

I'm trying to have it to:

- 1,000,000
- 10,000,000
- ect...

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) || 309320350
  number.toLocaleString();

  // Called the function in each second
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').text(number++); // Update the value in paragraph
  }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Please clarify why it doesn't work.

Comment: well calling `number.toLocaleString();` does nothing since you are not storing it... You should be calling it when you are outputting the number...

Comment: Gotcha, I looked at the code from the person below and get what you guys are talking about. Sorry, I'm a beginner at coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) returns a string and leaves the `number` unchanged. It doesn't "tell" the number how to be formatted later (the number doesn't remember), it does format it. You will need to call it when doing the `.text(…)` output.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var number = parseInt($('#test').text(), 10) || 309320350

  // Called the function in each second
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').text(number.toLocaleString()); // Update the value in paragraph
    number++;
  }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test"></p>
```